# Assembly Unrecognised Emulation Mode 32

Tags: assembly, x86, linker, nasm, ld

I tried to compile Assembly code:

```
; [Assembly Tests].exe
;
; Tests
; Author: Simpfey

global _start

section .text:

_start:
    mov eax, 0x4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, message
    mov edx, message_length
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 0x1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80

section .data:
    message: db "Hello World!", 0xA
    message_length equ $-message
```

using nasm and ld
command
`ld -m32 -o ./build/Assembly.exe ./build/Assembly.o`

gives me an error saying:
unrecognised emulation mode: 32

To specify more about my Os:
Windows 10 x64 Proffesional

Comment: `ld` doesn't support an `-m32` option.  What made you think that it did?  You might be thinking of `gcc -m32`.

Comment: Are you planning to run this under WSL?  It's Linux code and won't work natively on Windows.

Comment: You probably wanted `-m elf_i386` o `-m i386pe`.

Comment: @MargaretBloom It sorta worked, when i tried to run it loadded terminal and window was shown with text saying that : Assembly.exe Stopped working

Comment: That's expected if you run an `int 0x80` instruction in a native Windows program; that interrupt number isn't special to the Windows kernel, so it raises a #GP exception which the kernel catches.  See [Segmentation Fault: int 80h](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49784186) / [NASM tutorial uses int 80h, but this isn't working on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38269269) / [Displaying text in command line after executing a .exe file from a compiled .asm file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72611496)

Comment: @PeterCordes Im Confused And, I don't exactly don't know what to do with this information else, that knowing `int 0x80` doesn't work and I should change it to something else

Comment: If you want to follow Linux tutorials, set up a Linux VM such as WSL2.  Otherwise look for Windows tutorials, either 32 or 64-bit.  e.g. [How to write hello world in assembly under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1023593) .  Windows doesn't have a direct equivalent for `int 0x80`, at least not one that's documented and supported: [System Calls in windows & Native API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2489889) - you supported API is via the DLLs, although people have reverse-engineered the 64-bit `syscall`  ABI.